Accessing Socrata metadata using Python
I have some simple code that does not seem to be working
# pip install sodapy
import sodapy
# client = Socrata(
#        "sandbox.demo.socrata.com","FakeAppToken",
#        username="fakeuser@somedomain.com",
#        password="mypassword",
#        timeout=10
# https://data.cityofchicago.org/Administration-Finance/Current-Employee-Names-Salaries-and- Position-Title/xzkq-xp2w 
# https://data.cityofchi cago.org/resource/xzkq-xp2w.csv
client = sodapy.Socrata( "data.cityofchicago.org", "xzkq-xp2w")
metadata = client.get_me tadata("xzkq-xp2w")
print(metadata)

It returns a 403 error (forbidden?) is it a PEBUAC error? or is it an ID10T error on my side

what am I missing?
I've tried what I know and I just want all the metadata for that particular socrata site.
